# Do all sliding glass patio doors come pre-assembled in one piece?

Tags: doors, sound-proofing

I'm doing a soundproofing project in my basement, setting up a small home recording studio, and I need a door that doesn't swing. Looking at other studios, I notice that they often go with a double set of exterior sliding glass patio doors (air gap in between). I think this is a great solution since patio doors are designed to be air tight and insulate well (in Canada anyways) and shouldn't let a lot of sound through.

My problem is that all the patio doors I can find come with pre-assembled frames (72"x80"), and I won't be able to fit it around the turn in my basement stairs.

Where can I find glass exterior doors that come in pieces so that I can actually get it down to the basement?

Any other soundproof non-swinging door ideas out there? DIY options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question here as I found a door perfect for my needs. After asking the folks at my local home depot, I found out about a door called a 2 plus 2. That is, a sliding door with essentially 2 sets of glass doors in it. These doors are often used in houses to help insulate against more extreme weather conditions, and should work quite well for my soundproofing project.

http://standarddoors.com/products-high-quality-doors/the-original-2Plus2-aluminum

The best part, you can buy them in a knocked-down format! That is, completely unassembled so that one person can easily carry, transport and install. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

A swinging door would be very convenient in this case since you can very easily find a thick door, seal any gaps and install sound insulation. However, if you really won't be able to install a swinging door you might find this helpful:

***Door:***

You could install a soundproofing **sliding door**, with roughly the same money. I suggest installing above the door entry a slider. Now you can find a really **cheap wooden sliding door** that fits around the turn. You don't need to go for a glass door, it is more expensive and will be more difficult to soundproof. **A swinging door will do just as fine** if you tweak it and add some rollers on top of it. This is what requires the most effort because you need to be very precise with the measurements, in order to leave as small gaps as possible. (In fact, we did the same on a door we couldn't replace because it was too old, and we weren't able to find doors with those dimensions).

***Soundproofing:***

If the door is really cheap, then it is also probably **hollow** and that won't block the sound. You can install soundproofing material of your choice (you can find really good deals for old **foam mattresses** which do the job) on the side of the door that is always shown whether it is open or closed. Lastly, however good the measurements are, there will always be gaps on the sides. To eliminate this, you can glue some sort of **soundproofing strips** on the 2 walls on the side, the ledge above and on the bottom part of the door, so that they are a tight fit for the door.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Michael, agreed, a heavy swinging door would be more convenient, and it is an option I suppose, I just really don't want to lose the room space. Typically the DIY approach is to actually put 2 swinging exterior fibreglass doors together with an air gap in between, although that would result in losing space on both sides of the entry. The challenge of putting a door like that on a slider is making it seal tight enough to be soundproof. Hanging foam or mattresses on the door may be considered acoustic treatment for a room, but will do absolutely nothing in regards to soundproofing the room

Answer (score 0):

There are three possibilities I have for you.

In your sliding door scenario : one door is for first entry and the air Gap provides some sound insulation properties when traversing from one area into the other.

[Anderson Sliding Glass Door frame that requires assembly.](https://www.andersenwindows.com/-/media/aw/files/technical-docs/installation-guide/installationguide-0005310.pdf)

Here are some possibilities or a combination of the two items.

If you have the possibility to install a [pocket door](http://www.raydoor.com/explore-doors/pocket-doors/) this might allow you to achieve the same thing with the ability to install in pieces.

Also [revolving dark room doors](http://www.tedndt.com/cat/cat43.php) for the outer and the pocket door for the inner

Comment: Hi Ken, great answer, it shows that unassembled glass sliding doors do exist! I also really like the pocket door idea, although this would require a lot more work and creativity. I would have to make my wall thicker (so it could house a sliding door inside and still be soundproofed), and It would have to be heavy, thick, and sealed airtight when closed (for soundproofing). I am up-voting this answer, however I will be posting my own as I did some searching around this weekend, and found a door perfect for my needs. Thanks Ken